# Trouble encountered when launching pyspark with command prompt

Tags: python, pyspark

When i attempt to launch spark in command prompt with 'spark-shell', a new command prompt simply appears and does not launch spark. i used 'pip install pyspark' to install spark. Thank you for any help

Answer (score 0):

I had a virus 'malware' in my pc. I downloaded a malwarebyte anti-virus [here](https://fr.malwarebytes.com/). He cleaned up all malwares and now pyspark works well.